# Cleaning a mtb - contamination

Tags: mountain-bike

I have jsut come back from a ride on my new mtb, it has hydraulic disc brakes, what do I need to know about contamination and cleaning as I need to clean my bike now.
Any other tips would be useful to do with cleaning a MTB in particular? I am experienced in road bikes.
Thanks
Charlie

Comment: I've used a garden hose, mild soap, and a brush in the past with good results.  If you have ever been to a cyclocross race they use pressure washers to clean the mud off, sometimes every lap.

Comment: Pressure washers can force water past the seals of bearings in wheel hubs, bottom brackets and headsets, so home cyclists are usually encouraged to avoid water spray/pressure.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful

Comment: The main thing is that you should not use a pressure spray on any of the bearings or brake fittings, as this can force water into areas where it shouldn't go.

Comment: @Armand that _can_ perhaps happen if you use the strongest settings and point the washer right at the bearings. Otherwise it's a total non-issue; sensible use of a pressure washer is at least as safe as anything involving soap (which after all can also take some grease with it).

Comment: The pressure washers I've used at trail centres are permanently set to a fan rather rush a narrow jet, so will be much safer for bearings etc. I leave my own set the same way, even though I don't tend to bother getting it out for my bikes.

Comment: Don’t obsess about it, just get rid of the worst mud after a muddy ride. Use a hose, pressure washer, whatever. Lube the chain afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Same as cleaning a road bike (except I hope there is a lot more mud to wash off it :) )

To get ride of the mud, a soft brush with a hose, not a pressure washer, works well.

Once the worst of the mud is washed off, I use a bucket of soapy water hose (Dish liquid works well, it leaves very little residue so does not affect disc brakes) and the soft brush. Wiping dry with a clean cloth is optional, leaving it outside to dry is better than storing it inside wet (but don't loose sleep if you have to put it away wet). I will then oil the chain and leave it, or go for a deeper clean of the drive train depending on time and need.

Pay particular attention to the fork stanchions and shock. These should be cleaned after every ride regardless. Once the worst of the muck is off, wipe them with a damp, soft cloth.

Answer (score 4):

**The best tool to clean a muddy mountainbike is a low-powered pressure washer.**

*A brush and dish liquid?* Sure, that works too, but it *is* quite a slow hassle. Especially come autumn, it's already dark when you're back from the trails, and of course raining... way too tempting to just skip the wash and go right under the warm shower yourself instead. Which is a really bad idea, because the dirt keeps humidity to the metal for a long time. Even worse if you're living near the sea or in winter when there's salt on the roads.

My bikes thanked me bigly when I got a battery-powered pressure washer (Worx HydroShot), that makes the cleaning quick, effective and ... actually really fun, if you ask me. There's a lot of scare talk about pressure washers and bearings etc.. Yeah, be a bit careful. But good mountainbikes are designed to keep the critical parts protected anyway, and a battery-powered washer isn't powerful enough anyway to intrude in a small greased cavity. It *is* powerful enough to quickly wash off dirt from parts that are awkward to reach with a brush though.

Such a washer is particularly useful when the ride does *not* end at home or else where a hose is available: it comes with a swimming part and filter that you can just stick in any lake or creek, and then works just as well. Super handy for cleaning the bike before stowing it in the car.

Soap or similar is optional. If you want to get the frame really shiny then water pressure alone won't be enough, but... what's the point of a *shiny* mountainbike? What matters is that it stays is good condition.

As for disc brakes: obviously it's crucial to keep any kind of oil or grease away from the rotors, but also tensides. If you've gotten soap on the brakes, it's important to rinse it away completely. Not too difficult, but you need to remember it. With the pressure washer there can also be a problem: if there is a lot of wet lube on the chain, the water can spallate some of it off so it may land on the rear brake. So be careful from which angle you clean the drivedrain.

I'm not sure how important it is to dry the bike after cleaning. What I always do it to shift into the highest gear and rotate the cranks as fast as possible with my hand, so the drivetrain gets a bit centrifuge-dried, and bouncing the bike on the floor a couple of times. (If the bike can't handle that, it's not an MTB...) If it's raining, I then immediately apply chain lube, else it can't hurt to first let it air-dry a bit more.

Comment: A lot of people deprecate pressure washers. If you don't aim directly at where the bearing seals are, I bet this will not be too bad.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to some outdoor lawn or similar, wash your bike there.  Avoid washing it over concrete, and definitely do not wash it indoors unless you have no other option.

There are no special precautions for your hydraulic brakes, other than "don't be rough" and avoid touching the rotors.

**PROTECT** Remove all your accessories, like lights, pump, saddle bag, computer, etc.  If you have a leather saddle, remove that too.

**RINSE** Try and remove the largest gobs of mud by hand.  Use a gentle hose pressure and either your hands or a soft brush to agitate the dirt off.  Work from the top downward where possible.

**WASH** Then you can apply warm water with some *biodegradable* dish soap.  Use a soft rag/cloth to wipe across all the painted surfaces.

Depending on your particularness, you might use a small brush like a toothbrush to detail around the nooks and crannies like the headset, brake mounts, and any corners.

This is a great time to be looking for damage, loose bolts, kinked hoses, or anything that may need work afterward.

**RINSE-AGAIN**  Use a soft spray to wash all the soap/detergent off the bike.

**DRY** Move the bike somewhere in direct sunlight.  Lift the rear wheel and push the pedal hard to actuate the chain and transmission and flick off loose water.  Wipe down any chrome to prevent water spots with a soft dry towel or rag.  You can also wipe down paintwork.   Then wipe down the chain by turning the cranks backward while wiping.

Have a rest, check your email, etc.
**LUBRICATE**  Come back later when it has dried, and oil your chain with chain lube according to instructions.  Test the brakes and reconnect anything you disconnected for cleaning.   Reassemble anything you took off the bike, and check over your spares to make sure nothing's been used up - replace what's missing.   Then put the bike away inside.

Comment: Why should you avoid washing it over concrete, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush cos it makes a mess, and you'd need to sweep the concrete, or hose the mud off somewhere.  If washing the bike over grass then the knocked-off muck goes in the grass and feeds the lawn.   It's really pure laziness :)

Comment: I tend to pre-rinse mine over the front lawn if it's very muddy, but use detergent/degreaser on the driveway. Mine slopes towards a drain so it doesn't get too messy, except if lumps of mud land on it, and it's easy to rinse down.